# Вывод значения буфера обмена только при наличии нового значения буфера обмена

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проблема в том, что спамится print, а нужно чтобы выводилось **один раз** значение буфера обмена. Точнее, чтобы значение буфера обмена выводилось **как только** изменится его значение.

*Я понимаю, ничего удивительного в том, что спамится одно и то же сообщение, так как это **сообщение в бесконечном цикле**, но я видимо устала или сдеградировала ещё хуже что не могу сформулировать логику действий и посему прошу помощи.* :(

Код:

```
clipboarded = {}
default = clipboard.paste()


while True:
    if clipboard.paste() == 'texttext':
        # print("Yes, there is DEFAULT value.")
        pass
    else:
        print('No! There is new word:' + clipboard.paste())
        if clipboard.paste() not in clipboarded.keys() and clipboard.paste() != default:
            clipboarded[clipboard.paste()] = len(clipboard.paste())
            print(clipboarded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем ясно, зачем нужна переменная `default`? Для отслеживания какого-то специального значения? Если нет, и описанного словами функционала достаточно, то нужно что-то вроде такого, с запоминанием прошлого значения:

```
# можно поставить None чтобы вывести первое значение
saved = clipboard.paste()


while True:
    # сохраним значение чтобы не дёргать систему
    news = clipboard.paste()

    if news == saved:
        # ничего нового
        pass
    else:
        # обнаружено новое значение
        # сохраним, чтобы не повторяться
        saved = news
        print('New value: ' + news)
```

Если же я Вам ещё нужно дополнительное поведение, запоминание всех значений в массив / словарь, то это не сложно добавить. И в таком случае можно обойтись без переменной `saved`, просто проверять наличие значения в вашем списке / словаре.